# Best way to build a hierarchical tree from array having root and child conditions

Tags: javascript, recursion, hierarchical-data

I've tried to build a tree from results of dataset as array of objects, but IE have bad feeling with it.
The problem it's the timing.

I have to process data like this to build tree:

```
var DataSet = [{
     NodeId: 1,
     Label: 'Root',
     ParentId: null,
     Icon: 'icon'
  }, {
     NodeId: 2,
     Label: 'Children',
     ParentId: 1,
     Icon: 'icon1'
  }, {
     NodeId: 3,
     Label: 'Children',
     ParentId: 1,
     Icon: 'icon1'
  }, {
     NodeId: 4,
     Label: 'Children_lvl2',
     ParentId: 2,
     Icon: 'icon2'
}];
```

The conditions to be a child or root are objects:

```
var ForBeChild = { ParentId: '%@' }
var ForBeRoot = { ParentId: null }
```

Where '%@' is any value of object, set it also by condition:

```
var ColNameAsId = 'NodeId';
```

For order data as tree, I creating the following function:

```
var CreateTree = function (Parents, DataToAssign) {
        if (!Parents.length) return [];

        for (var i = 0; i < Parents.length; i++) {
            var ParentData = Parents[i];
            var Children = DataToAssign.filter(function (data) {
                for (var key in ForBeChild) {
                    var value = ForBeChild[key];
                    if (value === '%@') {
                        if (ParentData[ColNameAsId] != data[key]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (data[key] != value) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            });
            ParentData._children = CreateTree(Children, DataToAssign);
        }
        return Parents;
    };
```

Before calling it, I retrive the parents to pass as param:

```
var RootNodes = DataSet.filter(function (data) {
       for (var key in ForBeRoot) {
           if (data[key] != ForBeRoot[key])
               return false;
           }
           return true;
     });
```

Then build the all tree:

```
var JsonTree = CreateTree(RootNodes, DataSet);
```

Testing in IE 11.0.60 (Win10) - I know it's not the last - the timing for creating the tree it's 5/6 seconds.
The same code running into Chrome 70.0.3538.67 the timing it's around 1 second.

There is a way that can I improve the code? I need to reduce the timing of IE at minimum possible.

Thanks in advance.

Vale

Comment: a) Use a lookup structure to get a node by its id b) use a recursive function that builds new nodes whenever needed

Answer (score 1):

You could create the tree based on the ParentId and NodeId property, so that, there is no need to loop through the properties. it will reduce the time to create the tree.

Code as below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var DataSet = [{
        NodeId: 1,
        Label: 'Root',
        ParentId: 0,
        Icon: 'icon'
    }, {
        NodeId: 2,
        Label: 'Children',
        ParentId: 1,
        Icon: 'icon1'
    }, {
        NodeId: 3,
        Label: 'Children',
        ParentId: 1,
        Icon: 'icon1'
    }, {
        NodeId: 4,
        Label: 'Children_lvl2',
        ParentId: 2,
        Icon: 'icon2'
    }];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = PopulateTreeNode(DataSet, 0);
    });

    function PopulateTreeNode(data, parentid) {
        var newdata = data.filter(function (value) {
            return (value.ParentId == parentid);
        });
        newdata.forEach(function (e) {
            e._children = PopulateTreeNode(data, e.NodeId);
        })
        return newdata;
    };
</script>
```

the screenshot as below:

[image]